Collabora/code & custom WOPI service на одном хосте - как настроить взаимодействие по http?
Имеется:

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
локальное веб-приложение (.net core 8.0, Kestrel), реализующее в минимальном виде WOPI endpoints. Фактически реализация взята из примера https://github.com/CollaboraOnline/collabora-online-sdk-examples/tree/master/webapp/dotNET. Работает на http://localhost:5000.
Collabora/CODE (версия 24.04.7.1), запущенная как самостоятельный процесс (т.е. не в контейнере docker/podman). В coolwsd.xml отключен SSL, включен SSL termination, в настройках storage -> wopi задано alias_groups mode="groups", и в качестве хоста группы указан 127.0.0.1, плюс параметр storage -> ssl -> as_scheme выставлен в false.
Далее тестирую таким образом:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form
        action="http://127.0.0.1:9980/browser/61cf2b4/cool.html?WOPISrc=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5000%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F1"
        target="my-iframe"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="post">
        <input name="access_token" value="test" type="hidden" />
        <input type="submit" value="Test" />
    </form>
    <iframe name="my-iframe" height="1000" width="1000" allow="clipboard-read *; clipboard-write *">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>

(в качестве WOPIsrc используется url encoded адрес http://127.0.0.1:5000/wopi/files/1)
Сама коллабора после submit по кнопке Test сообщает, что Failed to establish socket connection or socket connection closed unexpectedly. The reverse proxy might be misconfigured, please contact the administrator. For more info on proxy configuration please checkout https://sdk.collaboraonline.com/docs/installation/Proxy_settings.html
А в логах коллаборы я вижу следующее:
TRC  #-1: new asyncRequest: GET 127.0.0.1:5000 /wopi/files/1?access_token=test&access_token_ttl=0| net/HttpRequest.hpp:1312
DBG  Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5000 (SSL)| net/NetUtil.cpp:379
.......
ERR  #30: Looks like SSL/TLS traffic on plain http port| wsd/ClientRequestDispatcher.cpp:646

Почему коллабора решила, что к 127.0.0.1:5000 нужно подключаться по SSL? И как заставить всё это хозяйство работать?
Спасибо.
